# Invalid data found in the last hls segment after transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

When I use `ffmpeg` to transcode some pure audio flv files to `hls` segments, the last `.ts` segment contains some decoding errors. It seems that it happens when the last segment's duration is short enough (about 1.5 second).

Here is my transcode command:

```
ffmpeg -i 111.flv -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f hls -hls_time 10.00 -hls_list_size 9999 tmp.m3u8
```

And output:

```
ffmpeg version n4.0.1-5-gb5106c5 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/zx/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/zx/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags='-L/home/zx/ffmpeg_build/lib -ldl' --bindir=/home/zx/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-debug
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, flv, from '111.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    date            : 2018-05-31 01:31
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
  Duration: 00:12:11.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 135 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp0.ts' for writing
[mpegts @ 0x26feb80] frame size not set
Output #0, hls, to 'tmp.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    date            : 2018-05-31 01:31
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp1.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp2.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp3.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp4.ts' for writing
......
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp71.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp72.ts' for writingx    
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp73.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x25d4280] Opening 'tmp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
size=N/A time=00:12:11.39 bitrate=N/A speed=84.7x    
video:0kB audio:11421kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[aac @ 0x25a0580] Qavg: 567.976
```

After transcoding, the duration of the last segment in `m3u8` file is 1.39 second:

```
....
#EXTINF:9.984000,
tmp71.ts
#EXTINF:10.005333,
tmp72.ts
#EXTINF:1.386667,
tmp73.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

But when I use `ffprobe` to parse the last segment, I got an error:

```
ffprobe -i tmp73.ts 
ffprobe version n4.0.1-5-gb5106c5 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/zx/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/zx/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags='-L/home/zx/ffmpeg_build/lib -ldl' --bindir=/home/zx/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-debug
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
tmp73.ts: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The input flv:

```
http://45.76.56.248/hls_transcode_fail.flv
md5sum: 4627bbb27bcb22c143ad4dfa47359650
```

Since my statistic module relies on the output of `ffprobe`, this exception will cause the entire transcoding task to fail. My temporary solution is to skip the last segment which is too short in the statistics phase. But I need a more reasonable and robust way to fix or bypass this issue. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow ffmpeg fails to add certain metadata to the last audio segment of an HLS stream, causing the `Invalid data found when processing input` error you're seeing when trying to probe the file with ffprobe or ffmpeg later, as they are unable to determine the format of the file, which you can see play out by setting `-loglevel trace` in your command.

The workaround is to add `-f mpegts` before your input to skip the format probing and force it to recognize the file as an MPEG-TS segment.

The solution is to run something like `ffmpeg -f mpegts -i /tmp/original.ts -c copy /fixed.ts` to fix the faulty segment.

You'll see the filesize increase in the fixed segment, as missing information is added to the file.

No idea why this is happening, but it has cost me a LOT of time to figure out what to do about it, hope it helps someone out.